# Regex of email addresses without having a separator

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract email addresses that are in a text list that have no separator that could be used the detect beginning and ending of the addresses. I have a string like this:

email1@hotmail.comwelcome@mydomain.atinfo@another-domain.detesting@domain.or.atmy.name_test@domainname.de

I am on the following state of the regex (not working):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.(com|at|de|or.at)
```

Would be very interesting if someone have a solution for this? Maybe also a better way to determine the domain ending than having a hardcoded list of all possibilities.

Comment: you can use`[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.(com|de|or\.at|at)` have a look at : https://regex101.com/r/gkPjrv/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need that list of hardcoded TLDs, otherwise there's no way of determining where one address ends and where the next one begins.

Your regex is not bad, but you need to escape the `.` (otherwise it will match any character if not enclosed in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)) and to allow underscores within your character classes:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\.(com|at|de|or\.at)
```

works for your examples.